# How to fetch foreign key relationships in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, foreign-keys, mongoengine

I have the following two models.

```
class URL(mongoengine.Document):
    codes = mongoengine.ListField(mongoengine.IntField(required=True),
               verbose_name='Codes')
    name = mongoengine.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)

class BytesForURL(mongoengine.Document):
    url = mongoengine.ReferenceField(URL)
    value = mongoengine.FloatField(required=True)
    timestamp = mongoengine.DateTimeField(required=True)
```

I need to get the data of `BytesForURL` given a `url` name within a time range. How do I query for that.

```
bytes = mongo_models.BytesForURL.objects(timestamp__gte=from_time,
                                                  timestamp__lte=to_time, )

for byte in bytes:
    print byte.value, byte.timestamp
```

But how do I pass get this value for a url. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
urls = mongo_models.URL.objects.filter(name=name)
bytes = mongo_models.BytesForURL.objects.filter(
            timestamp__gte=from_time,
            timestamp__lte=to_time, url__in=urls)
```